# How to properly manage WebAuthn challenges?

Tags: nonce, webauthn

I'm in the process of evaluating adding WebAuthn/Passkey support to a website, and I'm not really sure how to properly manage challenge nonces.

My understanding is that the main reason for using challenge nonces is to prevent replay attacks, but that implies that challenges need to have some sort of lifetime, and the lifetime to use isn't obvious to me, especially with the new [Conditional Mediation](https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/wiki/Explainer:-WebAuthn-Conditional-UI) mechanism that was added to support the easier login flow associated with Passkeys. Without conditional mediation, challenge management doesn't perhaps seem particularly difficult, I could easily imagine just keeping a fixed maximum number of challenges around and invalidating them with a reasonably short timeout.

With conditional mediation, however, I'm less sure. My understanding is that Conditional Mediation is basically supposed to be running as long as a page with an option for login is open, and it seems to me that any number of pages with an option to log in could be kept open by a user for days or months, basically indefinitely. It seems unreasonable to me that the login challenge should arbitrarily stop working just because the user has held the page open for longer than the arbitrary timeout I've set. Further, if many pages have a low-key option for logins, that seems like a potential lot of challenges to maintain.

- The only option I can think of is to simply not manage "active challenges", but rather just generate random challenges, perhaps even on the client side without the server even knowing about them, and rather have the server keep track of challenges that were actually used for a WebAuthn transaction, but wouldn't that conversely require keeping track of such used challenges forever?
- I mean, I realize that even thousands of authentications wouldn't generate a significant amount of data to store on today's systems, but it still seems inefficient, doesn't it?
- I'm also not sure if allowing any previously unused challenge could have some sort of security implications (the specification states that challenges should be generated in a trusted environment, but I'm not sure why).

Am I missing a more sane option? Are there any recommendations/best practices around how to manage WebAuthn challenges, particularly when using conditional mediation?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd add for anyone interested that, at least for now, I have settled on using one global challenge per web session that is "consumed" when it is used by any page under that session.

This is by no means a perfect solution, and in particular, one fault of it is that, if a user logs in on one page, then logs out again, then the current "login session" is essentially invalidated on other pages that are kept open, and they would need to be refreshed in order to get a new challenge. Not the most common use-case, perhaps, but there shouldn't really be a reason why it couldn't work, and I don't think it is entirely unrealistic.

As such, I won't mark the question as answered and still welcome better answers, but it might perhaps be useful to someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd follow up on this since I've changed the challenge scheme since my last self-answer.

Having considered my options and discussed some of the finer details with some WebAuthn professionals **(not to give the impression that this is a "vetted" solution, keep in mind rather that it's home-baked crypto with all of the associated caveats)**, as of now, I have instead settled on a stateless scheme using challenges with embedded, encrypted information. When generating a challenge, I collect the following information:

- A random nonce for some entropy (see below)
- A current timestamp
- A global, monotonically increasing challenge sequence number
- Other potential metadata that I may find useful

I format this information in a binary blob which is generally <64 B, append a SHA256 checksum of the data, and then encrypt said blob with a key that is kept secret server-side. I use AES in CBC mode with a zero IV (which is why I instead include a random nonce inside the blob, as the first piece of data, just to not need to communicate a separate IV). I then use this encrypted data as the challenge itself.

When validating a challenge coming back, I decrypt the blob again, and then perform the following checks on the data:

- Ensure the checksum is valid
- Compare the encoded timestamp with the current time, and check so that its age is reasonable (see below).
- Then, per account, I keep two pieces of information to validate the challenge counter: A fixed number of known seen, ie. previously used, challenge counters (currently 64), along with a single lower bound (initialized to zero). I check so that the counter in the challenge is greater than the lower bound, and not in the list of seen counters. Then, to "consume" the challenge, I add its counter to the list of seen counters, and if the list is then larger than its allowed size, I remove the least counter from it and replace the lower bound with that.

This scheme ensures a couple of things:

1. Current challenges (those that have not yet been consumed) are maintained wholly statelessly, putting no strain on server resources.
2. Used challenges are invalidated forever without requiring an unbounded amount of server resources, while still allowing for a reasonably large window of challenges being completed "out of order".
3. Challenges have a maximum age that can be validated.

In said discussions, I have been informed that the purpose of the challenge is not strictly for preventing replay attacks, but also to prevent "pre-play attacks", where an attacker may have temporary access to a FIDO key (eg. "borrowing" a victim's key while they step away for a few minutes, or other similar attacks) and can use such temporary access to pre-generate valid assertions only to use them perhaps days, weeks or even years later, which is why some maximum challenge lifetime is very strongly encouraged.

Now, having a maximum challenge lifetime still does conflict with the goals of conditional mediation, and there has been some talk in the community about fixing this via a scheme of delayed challenge creation, but that is not the reality yet. As such, the maximum lifetime I validate against may still be considered unreasonably long by some (at 10 days, currently). Not sure how I feel about that, but that's my current situation.

For anyone interested in further context, parts of this has been informed by [a bug report](https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1856) I filed on WebAuthn's GitHub project. Perhaps this can be useful to someone else.